# Deploying a maven sub-module to a repository for other projects to use (without parent)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

The problem is, in our company we have a project with multiple sub-modules, however one of the sub-modules is just a collection of API declarations and is meant for other (3rd praty) projects to use. I want to keep it as a sub-module because is easier to maintain and build (dependency and property inheritance). Other sub-modules in this project are also dependant on it.

The question I have is, if there exist a good practice or a nice way to execute a deploy phase that will upload just this sub-module to a different repository (can be duplicated too) without it having a dependency to parent pom.

What I have already tried:
I have already checked the deploy:deploy-file, but the problem is when it comes to SNAPSHOT builds. We wish to be able to publish SNAPSHOTS and release builds, and snapshots have different repository than release ones, but deploy-file goal can only have one url parameter. I do not wish to use different profile for snapshot deploy. Than I tried to use maven build-helper and its regex-property to be able to change the repository url if the version is a SNAPSHOT, but was unable to do so because of the plugin and regex limitations.

The last option is I can make a plugin for this, but I wish to know if there is a more elegant way to solve this the "maven way".

Comment: Just to make sure: You want to run `mvn deploy` but only actually deploy your "client" jar to the repository?

Comment: Yes, well we have 2 separate repositories one internal and one "public" and only the client module should go into the public one.

Comment: If the specific submodule requires a completely independent release strategy (version increment, scm tagging, different distribution repository and etc), the best "maven way" IMO is to separate and make it a standalone module.

Comment: The reason we do not want to completely separate it is because version, tagging, scm, and build configuration is the same as the parent, but only the generated jar should be separately deployed to another nexus repository, for 3rd party to use. This jar is the only dependency the 3rd party "plugins" need at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy this module separately but only for SNAPSHOT's for a release it does not make sense. The deployment of a module can be done via:

```
mvn -pl TheModuleYouWouldLikeToDeploy deploy
```

may be you need to add the option -am (also make dependencies) like:

```
mvn -am -pl TheModuleYouWouldLikeToDeploy deploy
```

Apart from that your approach sounds wrong cause if you are using a multi-module build why not deploying the whole build via mvn deploy ? May be it would be better to let do the job via a CI tool like Jenkins.

Comment: I think the -pl -am will not help, because the normal deploy also deploys the submodule's pom which has parent defined. So if create a new project that has a dependacy to said sub-module, the build will fail because maven will be unable to find the parent (eve tho is not needed)